# How to implement datamapper pattern with many-to-one relation?

Tags: c#, datamapper

I am writing a business application from scratch (in c#).

My data source is a legacy (sqlbase) database (I can not use EF, nhibernate, or any other orm).
I want to use the data mapper pattern for db->object mapping. The internet is full of useful c# (and other languages) implementations but no implementation used more than one table to populate the object.

My problem is that most of my business models doesn't fit with the db tables.
I need more then one table (sql query) to populate an object.

What is the best practice to implement datamapper with many-to-one relation?

Comment: you can't use any OR mapper?  then you  have to make it your self using datareader

Comment: No, because sqlBase does not support any common or mapper.

Comment: I think this will help you, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/522226/ADO-NET-cplustheplusrightplusway

Comment: This is a very good example for my question. In the "FindUsers" method he only uses one select statement and uses the command for the mapping (toList). What is the best way to map an object if i need multiple selects and can't use joins or views?

Comment: you just have to make selections and join them i your C# code then

Comment: Could you please give me an example how to do it?